# CodeIgniter: post variable not being read

Tags: php, codeigniter, post

I have a controller `user` with a method `login`

For some reason, when I call:

```
$this->post
```

I get an error `Undefined property: User::$post`

While, this works fine:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using:

```
$this->input->post('your_post_variable');
```